# I need load all the knockout.js templates and after execute a javascript function

Tags: knockout.js

I have implemented a knockout foreach binding, with multiple templates in the same page, i need that all the templates loaded and after execute a javascript's function. I use an afterRender callback, but not working.

**Index.js:**

```
var viewModel = function () {

  self.testPausa = function(){              

    var altoIzq = $('.listSecondaryMenu').height();
    var altodch = $('.materialContentBig').height();

    $("#datepicker").datepicker({

    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
    $("#datepicker_value").val(dateText);
    }
    });


    $("#otrodatepicker").datepicker({

    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
    $("#otrodatepicker_value").val(dateText);
    }
    });


    $('.titularContent h1').text("editar película");

    if(altodch > altoIzq){


    $('.listSecondaryMenu').height(altodch);


    }else{
    $('.listSecondaryMenu').height(altoIzq);
    }    

   };


}
```

**Index.html:**

```
<div class="divsecondaryMenu">
    <div data-bind="template: { name: function(){return templateSecundaryMenu(); } }">
</div> 

</div>

<div class="content">
<div data-bind="template: { name: templateContent, afterRender: testPausa}"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Javier, welcome to SO. It is considered bad form here, to introduce yourself and thank in the questions. The question is for just the questsion. You can introduce yourself on [your profile page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3668372/user3668372). You can thank people by [upvoting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) useful answers, and by [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer that suited you best.

Answer (score 0):

You have a ton of missing code in what you posted, but after adding the variables, functions and template definitions myself the testPausa function was running for me.

Code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/YtDj5/

You can tell it's running because of the "undefined is not a function" error at the `$("#datepicker").datepicker({` line.

Comment: @user3668372 Glad I could help :). Feel free to accept/upvote this answer.